# How do I make two images overlap eachother diagnoally to make two triangles?

Tags: css

How can I make two images be displayed like in my drawing below using CSS only? The photos are both perfect squares, and I understand that part of the image will not be shown by doing this. That is intentional. The gap in the middle is just my poor drawing skills, and it's not supposed to be there.

Additionally, if it is possible to have a nice fade effect between them where they meet, that would be even better, but I am assuming CSS is incapable of such magic.

[image]

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-and-custom-shapes-part-3/

Comment: By ‘fade effect’ do you mean that one should fade out while the other fades in for some width down that diagonal?

Comment: @AHaworth precisely

Comment: CSS masking to help with the fading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mask and CSS grid like below:

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: grid;
}

.box img {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  width: 100%;
}

.box img:first-child {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(45deg,#0000 30%,#000 70%);
}
.box img:last-child {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(45deg,#000 30%,#0000 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/582/400/400" alt="a wolf">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1074/400/400" alt="a lioness">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to wrap both images in a div tag with `position: relative` set on it and use `position: absolute` to position the images within it using the top, right, bottom, and left properties.

For the image clipping, I would recommend using a clipping path. You can use an online tool like this to generate the code you need easily:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

A code example can help me give a more specific answer if you provide one.